# R cannot be resolved to do a variable. After Add Libraries

Tags: android, eclipse, variables, import, r.java-file

I'm here stuck for 2 days already and I still cant fix this issue. I'm really new to programing so I'll ask you guys one question that is may be very often asked. I googled everything and still can't fix it.

I'm following developer.android.com for building my first app. and I am really stucked when trying to add activitybar on the app. I download libraries from sdk manager and i import them, after the succesful import i add them on my project (Project>Properties>Android>Add) and im facing 9 errors which are R cannot be resolved to do a variable, all of them are like that.
I read that section like 10 times and reinstalled everything and i still got that issue.
Please someone help me

Comment: Ensure there no any error in xml files. Also, check if xml files do not have any upper case in their name.

Comment: Im following developer.android.com and in their tutorials they say to make new activity called DisplayMessageActivity.xml and MainActivity.xml which are uppercase. Ill try to make new with lowcase

Answer (score 0):

I'm usually face this problem. 
Try to clean project then rebuild.

Comment: Tried that but still exist the problem

Comment: is R class still exits in folder gen\<your package>?

Comment: it exist but when i add the libraries it suddenly dissapear

Comment: Check the package name of R file (after adding library) with the your app package name. I think they are not same.

Comment: please check this link I made it better for understanding http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22936141/eclipse-add-libraries-in-project-im-stuck