# Eclipse, Add libraries in Project. I'm stuck

Tags: android, eclipse, addition, libraries

I'm stuck when Add libraries in my project in Eclipse. I am following this link [official android development website](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res) http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res and I do exactly what it says but I get errors for some reason.Here how it happends:

1.I download support libraries from SDK Manager.
2.I import them with existing Android Code into workspace and I press on the both .jar files Build Path>Add to Build Path.
3. Then on that project (made in step 2) I configure Build Path and I check both .jar files and uncheck the Android Dependencies and I click finish. Everything is okay for now.
But here comes the main problem=>
**4. I press on my main project (myfirstapp) properties and click Add and select the libraries** after that I press Apply and lots of errors raise up like *R cannot be resolved to do variable* and my R.id from /gen folder suddenly dissapear

I add now some screen shoots to make it better for you.
Sorry I have no reputations for posting images. Please copy links below

- [first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jv2hn.png)
- [second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Etonk.png)
- [third image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fithj.png)
- [fourth image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkEvT.png)

All my Codes: MainActivity.xml

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
     public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Displaymessageactivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

fragment_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        android:onClick="sendMessage" />
</LinearLayout>
```

strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">myfirstapp</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
    <string name="button_send">Send</string>
    <string name="title_activity_displaymessageactivity">Displaymessageactivity</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>

</resources>
```

Displaymessageactivity.xml

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Displaymessageactivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Get the message from the intent
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

            // Create the text view
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setTextSize(40);
            textView.setText(message);

            // Set the text view as the activity layout
            setContentView(textView);
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.displaymessageactivity, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.fragment_displaymessageactivity, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

fragment_displaymessageactivity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.myfirstapp.Displaymessageactivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Things I have tried so far:
1. Reinstall Eclipse and Java
2. Redownload libraries from SDK Manager
3. Clean the Project.
4. Make all my xml files starting with lowercase (but the MainActivity.xml and Displaymessageactivity.xml must start with uppercase)

I tried my best and I am stuck here forever. I am very frustated from Google :/
Every help is very appreciated and welcome!

Comment: After you add an application project to you project, sometimes you have to restart ecplise..

Comment: you mean after I import the libraries from SDK Manager right?

Comment: Check your imports at the top, remove the `R` import, save, hover your mouse over any `R` in your code and import it again. Or you can just check your imports to see if any of them throw any errors

Comment: @AngryAce no after you have added linking to your project..

Comment: @AngryAce In your work space you have 2 more projects android.support.v7 if you added that as library project you will get error. When you created a android project the android supported library are automatically included in android reference library. check your java build path in eclipse.

Comment: Make sure you are not using any repeated jar library.  If it's there in the reference libraries and in the project then remove it from import and export

Comment: @Yuvaraja I am newbie with Eclipse, so I do not import those libs for activity bar cause I got automatically included libs when I created the project?

Comment: @AngryAce Remove those application from the Eclipse.If u got any android library missing error,Right click the project >>> Properties >>> Android >>> Choose project build Target.

Comment: all right, i've fixed it thanks to your help. The problem was that I had 2 libraries added on 1 project so I removed 1 and it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

> Add the library to your application project:
>
> 1. In the Project Explorer, right-click your project and select Properties.
> 2. In the category panel on the left side of the dialog, select Android.
> 3. In the Library pane, click the Add button.

In step 3, notice that in the Library pane, you should see that the appcompat_v7 already be added (it's added automatically when you create your project follow MyFirstApp instruction, because you have already chosen minSdkVersion=8, not 11) (your second image).

So remove all the added libraries in the Library pane before adding your library (so in your third image it only has android-support-v7-appcompat in Library Pane), then the R.java will not disappear.